# How do Scrapy's feed exports work when writing to the local filesystem?

Tags: python, scrapy

I currently have a long running Python script in a screen session on an AWS EC2 instance that executes commands like

```
from subprocess import call 

call('''scrapy crawl my_spider -a year=2005 -a month=may 
--set FEED_URI=/home/ubuntu/my_spider/data/2005_may.json 
--set FEED_FORMAT=jsonlines''', shell=True)
```

over the set of all possible combinations of year, month for years 2000-2017 and months October-June.  Many of the individual commands have completed, and I can reattach to the screen session and see that it's scraping data properly, but I see no files in `/home/ubuntu/my_spider/data`.

Will the files appear after the Python script completes, or should I stop it now because something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileFeedStorage` opens file when crawler starts spider, so if output file didn't appear after start, apparently something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this doesn't answer the original question, but it still deserves mention.  The issue turned out to be that `call` was not parsing the `FEED_URI` and `FEED_FORMAT` options correctly, and thus was not writing the scraped data to the specified file.  Why this wasn't propagated back in some way, I don't know.  Changing it to

```
call(["scrapy", "crawl", "my_spider", 
  "-a", "year=2005", 
  "-a", "month=may", 
  "--set",  "FEED_URI=/home/ubuntu/my_spider/data/2005_may.json",
  "--set", "FEED_FORMAT=jsonlines"], cwd="/home/ubuntu/my_spider/")
```

worked, but it should be said that this is not [suggested practice](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html) for running Scrapy from a script.